# Cannot find module './models/user' | Node.js

Tags: node.js, module

I am making auth in node.js and I have a dir called `models`, and a file in there to make the user, called `user.js`.

In the `app.js` file is the statement `var User = require('./models/user');`, and yet it can't find that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add `module.exports = ... // function or object or other variable` in the `user.js` file at the bottom?